# What parameter do I pass for form1?

Tags: c#

I wish to update a `Label` from `form1` to `form2`.

I heard that if I want to access a form from another form, I need to put it in a constructor. So I did. To pass the information from `Form1`, I put that in the parenthesis.

I am getting the error that *`there is no corresponding argument`*. I do not know what parameter is supposed to be passed. What must I put?

```
 public void updateText(Form1 home)
    {
        home.txtOn.Text = "testing!";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("button clicked!");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateText();
    }
```

Comment: You need to overload the constructor in the second form.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass to the constructor the current instance of `Form1`.
To do that you must add to the second form constructor a `Form1` parameter
Example:

```
private Form1 home { get; set; }

public Form2(Form1 form) {
    this.home = form;
}
```

And in form when you create form2 you must pass `this`

```
Form2 form = new Form2(this);
```

And if you want change a value inside a control of Form1 you must use `Controls` collection